# OpenCV error in code

Tags: c++, opencv

I get the following two errors on my code.

'img.cv::Mat::cols' cannot be used as a function

'img.cv::Mat::rows' cannot be used as a function

and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me fix this error.

here is my code

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void salt(Mat &img,int saltvalue)
{
    for(int k=0;k<saltvalue;k++)
    {
        int i = rand() % img.cols();
        int j = rand() % img.rows();

        img.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0]=255;
        img.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[1]=255;
        img.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[2]=255;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Mat img;
    img = imread("C:\\castle.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    salt(img,3000);

    namedWindow("vOut",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("vOut",img);

    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cols` and `rows` are member ints of the [`Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) class, not member functions. Remove the `()`:

```
    int i = rand() % img.cols;
    int j = rand() % img.rows;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
int i = rand() % img.cols;
int j = rand() % img.rows;
```

img.cv::Mat::cols and img.cv::Mat::rows seems to be properties, not a methods of that class.